# Why from mobile not always see the highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use  highstock and it works great. Brings all the data and draws the graph accurately. 
The problem is that through the mobile does'nt always work, does not show the graph.

Is there a specific problem?? that at the moment I'm doing on the computer and it works excellent

what can I do ???

Comment: On which mobile are you trying it ? It seems that there are some limitations on Android: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility#android2

Comment: thank you, 
But how do you explain that sometimes I see and sometimes not???

Comment: How we can replicate your issues?

Comment: I mean that you should prepare live demo of your chart.